# Testing private variables - always bad practice?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, private-members

To give some background I've been learning java for about 10 months now so I am really not that experienced. I have been reading a bit recently on how how its bad practice to test private methods and variables.

In the perfect world you shouldn't do this as it suggests bad design - however, I am working with a legacy framework where most methods are called via reflection and it IS bad design, but I cannot change that no matter what. Please don't reply saying "you should redesign your code" as I cannot change the way the framework works.

I want to test that a 'flow' class behaves in a certain way and calls the right methods depending on the state of private variables, and I want to make sure that certain methods set private instance variables to a correct value if another private variable has a certain value. This is so when I make future changes to the class I can ensure that the flow/behavior of the class hasn't broken or changed.

Now, because the flow is based largely on the state of private instance variables and because its bad to test the state of private instance variables - how else do I test the class?

Ways of testing the private variables that all work:

1. Implement default access getters and setters at the end of the code and put the junit test class in same package. Comment these clearly that they should be used for testing only.
2. Make instance variables default access instead of private and put junit test class in same package. No other classes in the same package will instantiate this class anyway.
3. Test the private variables via reflection - I lose IDE functionality here as Eclipse won't refactor if I change the name of variables and could be a future pain of manually changing Strings to match variable names in the class to be tested.

Which of the three above is the "lesser" evil to use? Is it better to test private variables then have no tests at all?

Comment: You shouldn't be testing private variables. Test what the class *does*, not *how* it does it.

Comment: Chose Bohemian answer as the best answer. I am going to call the public methods in the order they would be called during the running of the application, and then see if certain methods call other methods.

The public methods called before the one I test should set the private variables to something that will make the methods act differently, and I can test that behaviour. One disadvantage this may bring is that if I want to add methods in certain bits of flow, I have to update my tests to reflect this and make sure they call that method too!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The state of private fields is irrelevant to the correct functioning of the class. You shouldn't be testing private variables.

Test what the class *does*, not *how* it does it.

If you want to test that the class sets its internal state correctly, so it behaves in a particular way after that, then call the methods that set the state and test that the behaviour after that is correct.

It doesn't matter if it takes 1000's of tests to ensure that - they are only unit tests, so they'll be fast.

Future coders are at liberty to change the internal workings of a class, as long as the class' contract is upheld.

Comment: One of the immediate problems I see when looking at my code after this response is that my methods do stuff, wait for a user to click something on a HTML page, methods do some more stuff, wait for a user to interact with some hardware, methods do some more stuff etc. 

Its impossible to mock some of these user responses, so the only thing I can do to kind of 'mock' or mimic them is by modifying private variables that would have been changed if the user interacted with the hardware or html page in a certain way.

Comment: Then break your class up to abstract the user interaction so you *can* mock it, or try harder to mock it (practically everything can be mocked!)

Comment: Which is exactly what I tried to do....but was told to revert back to the 'standard' design pattern!

I think I get what you are trying to say though. For example, I can call all the methods that would be called in the happyday flow (and in the happyday expected order) and then see if the last method (which usually calls methodX if variableY is set to true...which it should be if things followed the happyday flow) does in fact call methodX like I would expect it to. That way I do not actually have to test or set any private variables. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, it sounds right. It's OK for single tests to require many steps. However, the many steps required for a test suggest there may be some design problems with the code - perhaps the class is trying to do too much (cohesion) or store too much state etc. Again, consider breaking up the class into smaller classes each with tighter/narrower scope of concern and bring them together at a higher level. That way, you can test each of the parts separately, bring a few together at a time for some broader unit tests, and let system testing catch the big-picture tests.

Answer (score 0):

The first option would be a good choice for you.
While following a good coding practice, we should always make variables as private and methods to be public, so that variables can not be modified and methods can be accessed by outer world.